# Trying to transfer from one dataGridView to another accordingly

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

My datagridView1 contains 7 columns, and first one has dates. 
I'm trying to transfer january data from dataGridView1 to dataGridView2
I did try using a loop, which logically thought it would work, but it would give me nullExceptions

Here's my code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < f1.dataGrivView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
                if (f1.dataGrivView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Split('/')[1].StartsWith("01"))//if january..
                {
                    dataGrivView1.Rows.Add();//datagridview in current form
                    dataGrivView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = f1.dataGrivView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    dataGrivView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = f1.dataGrivView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                   }}
```

And after some googling, I saw you can't just copy data this way and you need to clone it, so I tried.

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in f1.dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewRow r = dgvr.Clone() as DataGridViewRow;
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvr.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains("/01/"));
                    r.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
                }

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(r);
            }
```

But.. same thing. 
Any idea?

Comment: date is in dd/mm/yyyy form, so either contains(/01/) or startsWith(01) works.

Comment: by clicking a button if you want to transfer first grid data to second grid, then i suggest you to keep two datatable and use datatable data to be transferred and grids will refresh data accordingly

Comment: Show how you initialized form `f1` inside another form. I think your `f1` is null

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed copy the first column values from a DataGridView to another.

```
for(int i=0; i<f1.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = f1.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
```

Any exceptions thrown are probably due to the new dataGridView1 not having the existing rows at the corresponding index in the iteration.

Comment: I did clone all rows from source dgv to the new dgv, and did that, and it still giving me a null exception. ._.

Comment: The above code will work if the DataGridView you're copying into has the matching rows to copy into. Otherwise can you please give the exact exception thrown.

Comment: NullReferenceException. I am also copying rows without data in it from source dataGridView, so they're pretty much the same.

Comment: NullReferenceException is being thrown because you're trying to access a Row or Cell's value that doesn't exists.